# Heading row doesn't appear in one line

Tags: html, css

I create a popup via javascript, below is the rendered html. I would like to have a headingrow containing the heading("Preisrechner") and both of the icons you see below. I can't really adjust them so that they are in one row. What should I do to get one row with heading and icons?

[image: example picture]
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ps281owc/)

```
<div style="display: table; top: 51px; right: 0px;" id="quickrechner" class="popup-wrapper">
<div class="my-popup-box">
    <div class="my-popup-heading"><h5>Preisrechner</h5>

        <div class="headingIcons">
            <ul>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-navigate-outline"></i></li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-close-empty"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-popup-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="col-md-4"><label for="e">EK - Preis:</label></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><input class="buyIn" id="e" type="text"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="col-md-4"><label for="d">EK - Preis:</label></div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><input class="buyIn" id="d" type="text"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.popup-wrapper{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:51px;
    background:#bdbdbd;
    z-index:10
}

.my-popup-box{
    display:table-cell;
    line-height:18px
}

.my-popup-heading{
    width:100%;
    padding-left:5px;
    float:left;

}

.my-popup-heading i{
    font-size:1.1em;
    font-weight:700;
    margin:0 8px;
    position: relative;
    float:right;



}

.my-popup-heading .heading-icons{
    position:absolute;
    right:10px
}

.my-popup-content{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:100%;
    padding:9px
}
```

***DESIRED RESULT:***

[image: desRes]

Comment: Post a fiddle with your example and someone can help.

Comment: @LShetty there's a fiddle in the question

Comment: basically the bootstrap classes you have add are wrong on many lvl's. if you still want to use those check the last lines of the css I have added in your fiddle to overwrite some properties:http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/ps281owc/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using bootstrap, so one solution would be this:

```
<div class="my-popup-heading"><h5 class="pull-left">Preisrechner</h5>

            <div class="headingIcons">
                <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                    <li><i class="ion-ios-navigate-outline"></i></li>
                    <li><i class="ion-ios-close-empty"></i></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

In basic you can give the icons and the heading different `floats` to achieve you desired outcome. `.pull-right` and `.pull-left` are the bootstrap classes to give floats.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ps281owc/3/)

Answer (score 1):

I created a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/quntgdo4/) with the simple changes you desired.

Here are the critical CSS changes:

```
.my-popup-heading h5{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
}

.headingIcons ul li{
  display: inline;
}

.my-popup-heading .heading-icons{
   display: inline-block;
   float:right;
   width:45%;
}
```

In order to have block level elements (`<h5>`, `<ul>`) on the same line, you have to use a display type such as `inline` or `inline-block`. And to have `<li>` on the same line, you have to use `display:inline`.

If I misunderstood, comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with:

```css
ul {
    float: right;
}
h5 {
    float: left;
}
```

You should wrap them of course. Otherwise they will apply to all h5 and ul tags...